# Skipping maven plugin for any version

Tags: maven

I'm guessing the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask anyway: Is there any (warning-free) way to omit specifying a version number for a plugin when all you want to do is skip it?

In my case, I am doing a custom deploy operation (using wagon), so I want to skip the standard deploy plugin deploy operation. I can do it with

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

But it seems dumb that I have to specify the exact version number just to skip it. I tried a version range, but that doesn't work, apparently by design/intention (based on some bug reports I found on the maven website (see below)).

Is there a simple cleaner approach?

FYI, potentially relevant maven issues:

- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3799
- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5251?focusedCommentId=292783&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-292783
- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2742?focusedCommentId=262427&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-262427

Comment: So what's the real problem to define a plugin version?  And what bug reports are you talking about?

Comment: the skip also maps to a user property: "maven.deploy.skip" - if you set that in properties nothing else should be necessary.

Comment: @wemu Thanks, that does just what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Does configuring through pluginManagement solve your issue?

```
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
  </build>
```